# Rust Diesel Abstract update function

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I currently trying to implement abstract function which will update a few meta fields for any table in the database, but getting problems with Identifiable.

I have a database where every table has meta-fields:

```
....
pub updu: Option<Uuid>, // ID of a user who changed it 
pub updt: Option<NaiveDateTime>, //updated with current date/time on every change
pub ver: Option<i32>, //Version increases on every change
.....
```

I want to implement a function which would make update for every entity. Currently I have this implementation:

```
pub fn update<Model>(
    conn: &PgConnection,
    old_model: Model,
    mut updated_model: Model,
    user_id: Uuid,
) -> Result<Model, diesel::result::Error>
where
    Model: MetaFields + AsChangeset<Target = <Model as HasTable>::Table> + IntoUpdateTarget,
    Update<Model, Model>: LoadQuery<PgConnection, Model>
{
    updated_model.update_fields(user_id);
    Ok(
        diesel::update(old_model)
            .set(updated_model)
            .get_result(conn).unwrap()
    )
```

When I am trying to call it it shows this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Marking: Identifiable` is not satisfied
   --> src/service/marking_service.rs:116:24
    |
116 |     web::block(move || common::dao::update(&conn2, real_marking1[0].clone(), marking2_to_update, jwt_token.user_id))
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Identifiable` is not implemented for `Marking`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <&'ident Marking as Identifiable>
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoUpdateTarget` for `Marking`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `testapi` due to previous error
```

An entity which I am trying to update in this example is:

```
use chrono::{NaiveDateTime, Utc};
use common::model::MetaFields;
use common::utils::constants::DEL_MARK_AVAILABLE;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;
use uuid::Uuid;

use crate::schema::marking;

#[derive(
    Clone,
    Serialize,
    Deserialize,
    Debug,
    Queryable,
    Insertable,
    AsChangeset,
    Identifiable,
    QueryableByName,
    Default,
)]
#[primary_key(uuid)]
#[table_name = "marking"]
pub struct Marking {
    pub uuid: Uuid,
    pub updt: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub ver: Option<i32>,
    pub updu: Option<Uuid>,
    pub comment: Option<String>,
    pub status: Option<String>,
}

impl MetaFields for Marking {
    fn update_fields(&mut self, user_id: Uuid) {
        self.updu = Option::from(user_id);
        self.ver = Option::from(self.ver.unwrap() + 1);
        self.updt = Option::from(Utc::now().naive_local());
    }
}
```

As you can see Identifiable is defined for this entity, but for some reason update cannot see it. Could someone suggest what I am missing here?
Update, schema:

```
table! {
    marking (uuid) {
        uuid -> Uuid,
        updt -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        ver -> Nullable<Int4>,
        updu -> Nullable<Uuid>,
        comment -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        status -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    }
}
```

```
diesel = { version = "1.4.6", features = ["postgres", "uuid", "chrono", "uuidv07", "serde_json"] }
r2d2 = "0.8"
r2d2-diesel = "1.0.0"
diesel_json = "0.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. The error message already mentions the issue:

`#[derive(Identifiable)]` does generate basically the following impl: `impl<'a> Identifiable for &'a struct {}`, which means that trait is only implemented for a reference to self. Depending on your other trait setup you can try the following things:

- Pass a reference as `old_model` `common::dao::update`
- Change the definition of `common::dao::update` to take a reference as second argument. Then you can separate the trait bounds for `Model` so that you bound `IntoUpdateTarget` on `&Model` instead.

(It's hard to guess which one will be the better solution as your question is missing a lot of important context. Please try to provide a complete minimal example in the future.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was almost complete example, I added a bit more details which I assumed was not necessary. I hope it will be enough. Please advice if there other information which could be useful.

Comment: @Dmitrii I'm unsure what else to say here. It's not about missing information in your question, but just that `#[derive(Identifiable)]` generates a `impl<'a> Identifable for &'a YourType {}`, which means it's just not implemented for the type itself, but only for references to the type. That means your code will likely never work that way, at least not without changing your update function.